# conditional regular expression in lexer

Tags: bison, yacc, lexer, flex-lexer

I want to put conditional check into lexer.l below line.But I am getting unknown error processing section when I tried to use pipe separator in the code.

```
LIMITLINEEND ((\n{2})|([a-z]))(Error : unknown error processing section)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start change occurences of [+-] to [-+].

Answer (score 0):

I should use parenthesis without using space. like ((a)|(b)) .